# How do I get from $\frac{-x+1}{-x+2}$ to $1 + \frac{1}{x-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

wolframalpha tells me it's the same but I can not follow how to get from one to another.

$$\frac{-x+1}{-x+2} =  \frac{1-x}{2-x} = \>? \dots$$

I don't get any further, always end up where I started.

Comment: @MichaelHardy What's the point in making two dollars (\$) ?

Comment: Try it both ways and you'll see the difference.

Comment: I see.. it's all about justification ;)

Comment: It's not just about justification; it also affects sizes and formats: $\frac 2 3$ versus $\dfrac 2 3$, $\sum_{k=0}^n$ versus $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n$, $\max_{x\in S}f(x)$ versus $\displaystyle\max_{x\in S}f(x)$, and numerous other similar things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{align} \dfrac{1-x}{2-x} & = \dfrac{-(x - 1)}{-(x-2)} \\ \\ &= \dfrac{x-1}{x-2} \\ \\ &= \dfrac {x-1 \color{blue}{\bf - 1 + 1}}{x-2} \\ \\ & = \dfrac{(x-2) +1}{x - 2}\\ \\ & = \dfrac{x-2}{x-2} + \dfrac 1{x-2}\\ \\ & = 1 + \frac{1}{x - 2}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Couldn't see that...

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Note: When you're stuck on such a rational function, or can't find a "tricky" way to manipulate a rational function, there's always polynomial long division!

Comment: I just introduced myself to [this technique](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac01/fac01.html) This particular term is actually an used in an integral exercise.

Comment: You... are a genius. I would have thought the step that you highlighted was pointless until I saw you factorize it.

Comment: @user132393 In the case, because the top and bottom have the same degree and lead coef, the long division algorithm boils down to subtraction, see my answer here, and, more generally, see [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/694204/242)

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{-x+1}{-x+2}\, =\, \dfrac{(-x+2)-1}{-x+2}\,=\,1+\dfrac{-1}{-x+2}\,=\, 1+\dfrac{1}{x-2}$$